# Flip each bit in Spark dataframe calling a custom function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark Dataframe that looks like

```
ID |col1|col2|col3|col4.....
A  |0   |1   |0   |0....
C  |1   |0   |0   |0.....
E  |1   |0   |1   |1......
```

ID is a unique key and other columns have binary values 0/1
now,I want to iterate over each row and if the column value is 0 i want to apply some function passing this single row as a data frame to that function
like col1 ==0 in above data frame for ID A 
now the DF of line should look like

```
newDF.show()    
     ID |col1|col2|col3|col4.....
     A  |1   |1   |0   |0....
myfunc(newDF)
```

next 0 is encountered at col3 for ID A so new DF look like

```
   newDF.show()    
         ID |col1|col2|col3|col4.....
         A  |0   |1   |1   |0....
    val max=myfunc(newDF) //function returns a double.
```

so on...

> Note:- Each 0 bit is flipped once at row level for function
>   calling resetting last flipped bit effect

P.S:- I tried using withcolumn calling a UDF but serialisation issues of Df inside DF

actually the myfunc i'm calling is send for scoring for ML model that i have that returns probability for that user if a particular bit is flipped .So i have to iterate through each 0 set column ad set it 1 for that particular instance .

Comment: why would you create so many dataframes for?

Comment: actually the myfunc i'm calling is send for scoring for ML model that i have that returns probability for that user if a particular bit is flipped  (so i have to iterate through each 0 set column ad set it 1 for that particular instance ..)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need anything particularly complex for this. Given that you have imported the SQL functions and the session implicits

```
val spark: SparkSession = ??? // your session
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

you should be able to *"flip the bits"* (although I'm assuming those are actually encoded as numbers) by applying the following function

```
def flip(col: Column): Column = when(col === 1, lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))
```

as in this example

```
df.select($"ID", flip($"col1") as "col1", flip($"col2") as "col2")
```

You can easily rewrite the `flip` function to deal with edge cases or use different type (if, for example, the *"bits"* are encoded with booleans or strings).

Comment: this code works fine if i just had to flip bits of columns but eventually i have to call a function which has some Logic of ML scoring results for each row ...(each col. that 0->1 has to go into the myfunc ) and retain the 0 at the end for that col before flipping next col.